# How to pass data between same level classes/component without using Navigation in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-component

Pass data from one class to another class that resides on the same level without navigating in react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `props` or `state` between two components that are on the same level within your  component tree is not possible in React. As a general rule of thumb in React: when two adjacent components need the same data, it is probably better to "lift" the property up a level in your hierarchy and pass the `props` to both components separately.